# FFMPEG When joining an audio track to a longer video track the audio loops

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am able to join video and audio files fine but if for example I add a 30 second audio clip to a minute long video, the audio will loop again once the 30 second mark is reached.

I want the audio to not loop so it should finish at the 30 second mark. I've looked around but couldn't find a solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve your desired aim by using the -filter_complex option and the apad filter option to pad out your audio with silence at the end if the video is longer.  Your command would be:

`ffmpeg -i videofile.mp4 -i audiofile.wav -filter_complex " [1:0] apad " -shortest output.mp4`

This assumes the audio you want is in the first stream of audiofile.wav, the [A:B] syntax says to take the B'th stream from the A'th input (both starting with 0, so [1:0] is the 1st stream from the 2nd input, or audiofile.wav above).

Details at:
https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-68